# Can you redirect external calls to private methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Lets say for example I have a class Foo with a private method bar.

```
class Foo
  private
  def bar
    # private Foo stuff
  end
end
```

And I need the bar method to remain private and unused, but I also need to be able to call the same method name and redirect it's behavior to class Baz's public method bar.

```
class Baz
  def bar
    # public access bar
  end
end
```

So without touching Foo's private bar can I implement something like method_missing for any calls towards private methods.

```
class Foo
  def private_methods(meth, *args, &block) # something like method_missing
    if meth.is_private?
      Baz.send meth, *args, &block
    end
  end
end
```

Foo is a grumpy person who doesn't want to share his bar.  Anyone who knocks on his door to ask for his bar he sends down the road to Baz's house who keeps an open bar.

I would like it to work like method missing.  So I don't have to define every single method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `method_missing`, as you suggested?

```
def method_missing(meth, *args)
  puts "method_missing invoked with meth = #{meth}"
  if(meth==:bar)
    Baz.new.bar
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Then

```
Foo.new.bar
#=> method_missing invoked with meth = bar
#=> public bar of Baz
```

`method_missing` is invoked because `Foo` has no pubic method `bar`.

Suppose `Foo` has a method that calls `bar`:

```
def call_bar
  bar
end
```

Then,

```
Foo.new.call_bar
  #=> private bar of Foo
```

as expected.

Comment: Thanks!  I was basing my thoughts on the fact that private methods raise their own error and weren't technically a "missing" method.  But this works well. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Since the method exists, I don't think you can use method missing. You can do something like below

```
class Foo
  def public_bar
    #public bar
    puts "public bar of Foo"
    Baz.new.bar
  end

  private
  def bar
    #private
    puts "private bar of Foo"
  end

  alias_method :private_bar, :bar
  alias_method :bar, :public_bar
end

class Baz
  def bar
    puts "public bar of Baz"
  end
end
```

So when you call bar, it will call `public_bar`

```
Foo.new.bar

=> public bar of Foo
=> public bar of Baz
```

Not sure if this will work for your scenario, but worth the try